# Deeply nested async request is not executing. Need help fixing or with debugging suggestions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

I'm working on a cache warming script in node. It's using both the Async and Request npm modules. The only real changes in the example code are variable names and values.

```
var languages = ['es', 'en'];
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';
var presents = [1,2,3,4];
var foods = ['green eggs', 'roast beast', 'potatas'];

async.each(languages, function (lang, callback) {

    async.each(whos, function (who, callback2) {

        request.get(baseUrl + lang + '/' + who, function (err, res, body) {
            var grinches = body;

            async.each(grinches, function (grinch, callback3) {

                    async.each(presents, function (present, callback4) {

                        async.each(foods, function (food, callback5) {
                            var finalUrl = baseUrl + lang + '/comp/' + who + '/' + grinch + '/' + present + '/' + food;

                            console.log(finalUrl);
                            request.get(baseUrl + 'en/ac', function (error, response, body) {
                                console.log(error);
                                console.log(response);
                                console.log(body);
                                callback5();
                            });
                        }, function () {
                            callback4();
                        });

                    }, function () {
                        callback3();
                    });

                });
            }, function () {
                callback2();
            });

        });
    }, function () {
        callback();
    });

}, function () {
    cb(null, 7);
});
```

In this example the finalUrl successfully logs but nothing within the immediately following request will log. If I grab one of the finalUrl's and drop it in a browser the request will process correctly. Is there some kind of stack limit within Async or Request that I'm possibly hitting?

If instead of making requests a that point, I push the urls into an array and then loop over that to make requests from the final async.each callback they will work. However, this solution has performance (memory) issues because I have to maintain massive fast-growing arrays. Here's an example of that solution

```
var languages = ['es', 'en'];
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';
var presents = [1,2,3,4];
var foods = ['green eggs', 'roast beast', 'potatas'];
var urls = [];

async.each(languages, function (lang, callback) {

    async.each(whos, function (who, callback2) {

        request.get(baseUrl + lang + '/' + who, function (err, res, body) {
            var grinches = body;

            async.each(grinches, function (grinch, callback3) {

                    async.each(presents, function (present, callback4) {

                        async.each(foods, function (food, callback5) {
                            var finalUrl = baseUrl + lang + '/comp/' + who + '/' + grinch + '/' + present + '/' + food;

                            urls.push(finalUrl);
                        }, function () {
                            callback4();
                        });

                    }, function () {
                        callback3();
                    });

                });
            }, function () {
                callback2();
            });

        });
    }, function () {
        callback();
    });

}, function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        request.get(urls[i], function (err, res, body) {
            console.log('this works');
        })
    }
});
```

What else might I try?

Comment: Try to use `async.eachSeries` instead of `async.each`, "each" makes use of parallel execution while "eachSeries" implements a single task at a time.

Comment: When switching to async.eachSeries I quickly get " Maximum call stack size exceeded" from async. Is there a specific reason why the request module would be failing with heavy parallel execution?

Comment: Yes there is, most likely you're not hitting a final callback where the stack gets released, if you are "so sure" that a final callback is getting called then try to execute your node script with the option `--stack-size` for node.js v0.10.x or `--max-stack-size` with the other versions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It took slowly going through and rewriting the structure using eachSeries to ensure I wasn't missing any callbacks, but it's working now and I have a lot more working knowledge of the async lib.

Comment: I am going to put this as an answer, please accept it so that it will be useful for the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) will execute all the tasks in *parallel*, this might cause some performance issues specially when there are a lot of tasks in the tasks array, as a work around "**though it might be slower in execution!**" you might want to use [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) to insure that all your tasks run *one by one* instead of executing them in parallel.